# How to pipe many bash commands from python?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, pipe

Hi I'm trying to call the following command from python:

```
comm -3 <(awk '{print $1}' File1.txt | sort | uniq) <(awk '{print $1}' File2.txt | sort | uniq) | grep -v "#" | sed "s/\t//g"
```

How could I do the calling when the inputs for the comm command are also piped?

Is there an easy and straight forward way to do it?

I tried the subprocess module:

```
subprocess.call("comm -3 <(awk '{print $1}' File1.txt | sort | uniq) <(awk '{print $1}' File2.txt | sort | uniq) | grep -v '#' | sed 's/\t//g'")
```

Without success, it says:
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Or do I have to create the different calls individually and then pass them using PIPE as it is described in the subprocess documentation:

```
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: If you *must* do this, it'll be a lot easier if you have your `awk` do all the work of `sort` and `uniq` rather than splitting that into three separate commands in each side of the pipeline.

Comment: BTW -- which version of Python? The change in default behavior for `close_fds` between 2 and 3 impacts this code.

Comment: The version of python that I'm using is 2.7

Comment: Ahh. That being the case, the second half of my answer (showing `subprocess.Popen()`) won't work unmodified. I might take a shot at it at some point, but not right now.

Comment: By the way -- if your filenames aren't fixed, you might consider passing them out-of-band from the code to avoid shell injection attacks. If you don't do that, *at least* use the `pipes.quote()` function to escape them before substituting into the string passed to the shell interpreter.

Comment: You have been very helpful, its no necessary. i will go on from there. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Process substitution (`<()`) is bash-only functionality. Thus, you need a shell, but it can't be just any shell (like `/bin/sh`, as used by `shell=True` on non-Windows platforms) -- it needs to be *bash*.

```py
subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', "comm -3 <(awk '{print $1}' File1.txt | sort | uniq) <(awk '{print $1}' File2.txt | sort | uniq) | grep -v '#' | sed 's/\t//g'"])
```

By the way, if you're going to be going this route with arbitrary filenames, pass them out-of-band (as below: Passing `_` as `$0`, `File1.txt` as `$1`, and `File2.txt` as `$2`):

```py
subprocess.call(['bash', '-c',
  '''comm -3 <(awk '{print $1}' "$1" | sort | uniq) '''
  '''        <(awk '{print $1}' "$2" | sort | uniq) '''
  '''        | grep -v '#' | tr -d "\t"''',
  '_', "File1.txt", "File2.txt"])
```

---

That said, the best-practices approach is indeed to set up the chain yourself. The below is tested with Python 3.6 (note the need for the `pass_fds` argument to `subprocess.Popen` to make the file descriptors referred to via `/dev/fd/##` links available):

```py
awk_filter='''! /#/ && !seen[$1]++ { print $1 }'''

p1 = subprocess.Popen(['awk', awk_filter],
                      stdin=open('File1.txt', 'r'),
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-u'],
                      stdin=p1.stdout,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p3 = subprocess.Popen(['awk', awk_filter],
                      stdin=open('File2.txt', 'r'),
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p4 = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-u'],
                      stdin=p3.stdout,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p5 = subprocess.Popen(['comm', '-3',
                       ('/dev/fd/%d' % (p2.stdout.fileno(),)),
                       ('/dev/fd/%d' % (p4.stdout.fileno(),))],
                      pass_fds=(p2.stdout.fileno(), p4.stdout.fileno()),
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p6 = subprocess.Popen(['tr', '-d', '\t'],
                      stdin=p5.stdout,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = p6.communicate()
```

This is a lot more code, but (assuming that the filenames are parameterized in the real world) it's also *safer* code -- you aren't vulnerable to bugs like ShellShock that are triggered by the simple act of starting a shell, and don't need to worry about passing variables out-of-band to avoid injection attacks (except in the context of arguments to commands -- like `awk` -- that are scripting language interpreters themselves).

---

That said, another thing to think about is just implementing the whole thing in native Python.

```py
lines_1 = set(line.split()[0] for line in open('File1.txt', 'r') if not '#' in line)
lines_2 = set(line.split()[0] for line in open('File2.txt', 'r') if not '#' in line)
not_common = (lines_1 - lines_2) | (lines_2 - lines_1)
for line in sorted(not_common):
  print line
```

Comment: does `sed` like tabulation char, or do you need to escape it?

Comment: Good question. I'm actually in the middle of a rewrite that moves more of the work into `awk`.

Comment: tabulations work in sedfiles. But in command line, I wouldn't risk it :) You could replace `sort | uniq` by `sort -u`, or maybe leave that on the python side. All those commands are not required, that could be done very simply with pure python, `set`, `sorted`, `split`

Comment: Would `Popen.communicate` with `stdout=PIPE` be appropriate in this case?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm sure pure python could do it even better, but that would be too much a rewrite of OP code. Your answer shows that you master awkython.

Comment: Great answer! This is pretty neat; I'll be saving this one

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, ...given as pure-Python was all of three lines (before output), it wasn't much work to add. :)

Comment: (The tabs don't need to be dealt with in that case because they're purely generated by `comm`, to distinguish between items unique to set-1 and items unique to set-2; if they'd been present in the literal data, emitting only the first column from `awk` would have removed them).

Answer (score 0):

Also checkout plumbum. Makes life easier

http://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

[Pipelining](http://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/local_commands.html#pipelining)

This may be wrong, but you can try this:

```
from plumbum.cmd import grep, comm, awk, sort, uniq, sed 
_c1 = awk['{print $1}', 'File1.txt'] | sort | uniq
_c2 = awk['{print $1}', 'File2.txt'] | sort | uniq
chain = comm['-3', _c1(), _c2() ] | grep['-v', '#'] | sed['s/\t//g']
chain()
```

Let me know if this goes wrong, Will try to fix it.

Edit: As pointed out, I missed the substitution thing, and I think it would have to be explicitly done by redirecting the above command output to a temporary file and then using that file in the argument to comm.

So the above would now actually become:

```
from plumbum.cmd import grep, comm, awk, sort, uniq, sed 
_c1 = awk['{print $1}', 'File1.txt'] | sort | uniq
_c2 = awk['{print $1}', 'File2.txt'] | sort | uniq
(_c1 > "/tmp/File1.txt")(), (_c2 > "/tmp/File2.txt")()
chain = comm['-3', "/tmp/File1.txt", "/tmp/File2.txt" ] | grep['-v', '#'] | sed['s/\t//g']
chain()
```

Also, alternatively you can use the method described by @charles by making use of mkfifo.

Comment: Could you add an example of using that tool for the OP's test case in your answer? (Generally, an answer is expected to have enough content to still be useful standing on its own even if all its links fail).

Comment: That's passing the *output* from the `awk | sort | uniq` as arguments to `comm`. That's not what command substitutions do -- instead, they evaluate to a *filename* which, when read from, will provide the output of the other command.

Comment: ...so, in practice, running the above fails in a manner akin to ```plumbum.commands.processes.ProcessExecutionError: Command line: ['/usr/bin/comm', '-3', '0', '#\na\nb\n', '', '0', '#\nb\nc\n', '']```.

Comment: I think I missed the redirection operation

Comment: See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst for details on the operation in question.

Comment: (argh, I badly misspoke above -- I said "that's not command substitutions do", but it's *exactly* what command substitutions do. What it isn't is what *process* substitutions do, and it's process substitution syntax being used to pass filenames that, when read, emit the output of the `awk|sort|uniq` pipelines as arguments to `comm`)

Comment: Hehe, Yeah, plumbum does not support substitutions in a way that is natural, we will have to manually redirect the output to a temporary file.. :(

Comment: Notably, that's a less efficient operation than what the process substitution does, since the latter starts all processes concurrently connected by FIFOs and makes content available to be read by `comm` as soon as it's emitted by `uniq`. (Granted, `sort` has to buffer the entire content regardless, but if we had pre-sorted inputs and could eliminate that step, then the parallelization difference would be substantial).

Comment: ...hmm. I suppose you could use `mkfifo()` (twice, one for each pipeline) from Python and hook it up that way.

Comment: I will try that out. Thanks

Comment: (if it's any help -- `mkfifo fifo{1,2}; awk '{print $1}' File1.txt | sort | uniq >fifo1 & awk '{print $1}' File2.txt | sort | uniq >fifo2 & comm -3 fifo1 fifo2 | grep -v '#' | sed 's/\t//g'; rm fifo{1,2}` is how one might write that for a POSIX-style shell without process substitutions).