# How to do process substitution, e.g. "echo hi | tee >( gzip > /tmp/1 ) > /tmp/2" in plumbum?

Tags: python, process-substitution, plumbum

I need to figure out how to call pipe substitution in plumbum. Specifically, how to construct chains such as `echo hi | tee >( gzip > /tmp/1 ) > /tmp/2`? Or, to illustrate the illustrate the idea better, `find / | tee >( grep hi > /tmp/grepped ) > /tmp/nongrepped`? I need this kind of approach because the equivalent of `find /` that I'm going to use is very expensive to run and I can't save it on disk, so I need to apply two different filters in parallel. Is there a way to avoid `mkfifo`?

Note: I'm aware that the question is similar to "[How to pipe many bash commands from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43812939/1091116)". The difference, though, is that I'm asking specifically about plumbum and an attempt to write a plumbum-related answer there is flawed, as described in its comments.

Comment: It'll probably be easier to just do it with `subprocess.Popen` directly. That package doesn't have a tee modifier that works the way you want, nor really any way to pipe stderr (as far as I can tell).

Comment: You're asking for process substitution, not command substitution. And if plumbum doesn't support that construct, you'll need to do it the old way -- by creating named FIFOs and piping to and from them... or just use `subprocess.Popen` directly, which is what I'd do. No point to adding an extra layer of abstractions when they aren't expressive enough to handle your real use case (without plastering on complexity, which is just what abstractions are built to avoid!).

Answer (score -1):

To replicate the command in the title of the question (`echo hi | tee >( gzip > /tmp/1 ) > /tmp/2`), you can do the following with `plumbum`

```
from plumbum.cmd import echo, tee, gzip

(echo["hi"] | tee["/tmp/2"] | gzip > "/tmp/1")()
```

This pipes the string "hi" to the `tee` function which writes it to "/tmp/2" and also copies it to stdout. Then, stdout is piped to gzip whose output is redirected to "/tmp/1".

To achieve something similar with your other command (`find / | tee >( grep hi > /tmp/grepped ) > /tmp/nongrepped`)

you can do:

```
from plumbum.cmd import find, grep, tee

(find["/"] | tee["/tmp/nongrepped"] | grep["hi"] > "/tmp/grepped")()
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I asked for. I really need command substitution, even if the example doesn't show that.

Comment: @d33tah Ok no worries. Can I recommend changing the title of your question to highlight that command substitution is what is important here? Or maybe add the command-substitution tag? That might help you attract an answer that solves your problem.