# How to emulate backtick subshells in plumbum

Tags: python, plumbum

I want to write this command in Plumbum:

```
foo `date +%H%M%S`
```

or, equivalently:

```
foo $(date +%H%M%S)
```

(think of 'foo' as a command like 'mkdir')

How can I write this in Plumbum?  I want to have this as a Plumbum object that I can reuse - ie each time I call it I call 'foo' with the current time, being different each call.

I tried using a subshell.  This example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from plumbum import local
import time
s = local["sh"]
f = s["-c", "mkdir", "$(date +%H%M%S)"]
for i in range(0,10):
  f()
  time.sleep(1)
```

doesn't work because I get:

```
plumbum.commands.processes.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected exit code: 1
Command line: | /usr/bin/sh -c mkdir '$(date +%H%M%S)'
Stderr:       | mkdir: missing operand
              | Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.
```

I could use `time.localtime()` to compute the time in Python, but that would be the same for every evaluation.  I could also generate a shell script file with this in, but then I'd have to clean that up afterwards.

How can I write this in a Plumbum-native way?

Comment: The advice I gave not to use plumbum in the comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49591046/how-to-do-command-substitution-e-g-echo-hi-tee-gzip-tmp-1-tmp-2 arguably applies here too.

Comment: To quote: *[I]f plumbum doesn't support that construct, you'll need to do it the old way [...] or just use `subprocess.Popen` directly, which is what I'd do. No point to adding an extra layer of abstractions when they aren't expressive enough to handle your real use case (without plastering on complexity, which is just what abstractions are built to avoid!).*

Comment: BTW, the shell feature you're asking about is called a "command substitution".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You came close to having something that would work with `sh -c`. The trick is to understand that *only the one argument directly after the `-c` is parsed as code by the shell*; subsequent arguments go into `$0`, `$1`, etc. in the context in which that code is executed.

```
s = local['sh']
f = s['-c', 'mkdir "$(date +%H%M%S)"']
```

That said, I'd strongly argue that plumbum is being more of a hinderance than a help, and suggest getting rid of it outright.

Comment: Thanks, that works. The reason for using plumbum here is it makes it easier to construct and pass around unevaluated commands (eg as function arguments or in lists etc) that can be composed and evaluated later.  That's hard to do with other approaches such as static Python functions.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to do it using Plumbum API, but introducing a wrapper function works:

```
import time
from plumbum.cmd import mkdir, date


def mkdate():
    return mkdir[date['+%H%M%S']()]


for i in range(0, 3):
    mkdate()
    time.sleep(1)
```

`mkdate` is a regular function, unfortunately, not a Plumbum object, but I haven't found anything in the docs right away =)